# @Autowired not managed in spring mvc "Injection of autowired dependencies failed"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

im trying to inject a bean into my class java ValiderBR

```
 @Service
 public class ValiderBR extends BusinessRule {
  @Autowired
    ILog logger;
...
}
```

but i have an error of injection caused by the @Autowired annotation

```
22 mai 2013 14:44:02 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'validerBR': Injection   of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: ma.co.services.log.ILog awb.businessrules.WorkflowIndividu.ValiderBR.logger; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [ma.co.services.log.ILog] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1122)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1267)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1186)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1081)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field:    ma.co.services.log.ILog awb.businessrules.WorkflowIndividu.ValiderBR.logger; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [ma.co.services.log.ILog] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at  org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at  org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type  [ma.co.services.log.ILog] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:986)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:856)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
... 32 more
22 mai 2013 14:44:02 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
GRAVE: La servlet /appExempleSpring-web a généré une exception "load()"
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type  [ma.co.services.log.ILog] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as  autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:  {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:986)
at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:856)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1122)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1267)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1186)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1081)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
22 mai 2013 14:44:02 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
```

and there is my configuration in spring-servlet.xml

```
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="client.controller" />  

    <context:component-scan base-package="ma" />  
    <context:component-scan base-package="awb" />  

   <bean id="jspViewResolver"
       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
       <property name="viewClass"
          value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
       <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
       <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
```

and there is my ILog interface

```
public interface ILog {


void debug(String msg);

void debug(String msg, Throwable t);

void error(String msg);

void error(String msg, Throwable t);

void fatal(String msg);

void fatal(String msg, Throwable t);

void info(String msg);

void info(String msg, Throwable t);

void warning(String msg);

void warning(String msg, Throwable t);
```

}

and there the class that implement the ILog interface

```
public class Slf4jLogger implements ILog {
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Slf4jLogger.class);

public void debug(String msg) {
    logger.debug(msg);
}

public void debug(String msg, Throwable t) {
    logger.debug(msg, t);
}

public void error(String msg) {
    logger.error(msg);
}

public void error(String msg, Throwable t) {
    logger.error(msg, t);
}

public void fatal(String msg) {
    logger.error("FATAL ERROR:" + msg);
}

public void fatal(String msg, Throwable t) {
    logger.error("FATAL ERROR:" + msg, t);
}

public void info(String msg) {
    logger.info(msg);
}

public void info(String msg, Throwable t) {
    logger.info(msg, t);
}

public void warning(String msg) {
    logger.warn(msg);
}

public void warning(String msg, Throwable t) {
    logger.warn(msg, t);
}
```

}

Thank's in advance for help.

Comment: Are you sure you have bean implementing ILog in context? Can you post full stacktrace?

Comment: @leo I edited the post and put my full stacktrace

Comment: Do you have a class that implements ILog that is being created as a spring bean (using @Component/@Service or directly in XML)?

Comment: yes, I added my class that implement ILog to my post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring can inject only beans that are instantiated in its context.

So, your class must be in the package in which you activated component scan using `@Component/@Service/@Repository` annotations.

Or, you can instantiate it in XML:

```
<bean id="iLog" class="my.package.Slf4jLogger"/>
```